# Java OS X app not running correctly from finder

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, permissions, hidapi

I am building a Java app using Netbeans that is targeted for both Windows and OS X. It uses HIDAPI to communicate with a HID device.

When we package for OS X if we use the terminal to launch the app:

```
open app.app
```

It opens and works correctly.

However if we double click the built .app file from finder the application loads but the HIDAPI dies when trying to list the devices from the system.

Has anyone else has a similar issue to this? We were thinking it might be a USB permissions issue with OS X but unsure as to why it works if you execute it from the Terminal?

App runs fine using the .EXE installer that is build for Windows.

Technical info:

JVM: jdk1.8.0_31.jdk
Classpath: lib/hidapi-1.1.jar
OS X Version: 10.10.2

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I'm wondering if the program can't find the required native libraries?

Comment: Hi MadProgrammer, I did look into that and I found that the working directories are the same for when the app is run from Terminal or Finder.